# Objects inside of transposed array don't reflect changes

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am making a `Grid` class for "Connect Four": I create strings array from `Square` objects, and then create columns array by calling `transpose` method on strings array:

```
class Grid
  Square = Struct.new(:state)

  def initialize
    @grid_strings = Array.new(6) { Array.new(7) {Square.new} }
    @grid_columns = @grid_strings.transpose
  end
```

And I have a method that puts a symbol to the end of chosen column by changing the `state` attribute of proper `Square` instance:

```
  def put_to_column(column_index, symbol)
    column = @grid_columns[column_index - 1]
    loop do
      square = column.pop
      raise "Full column" if square.nil?
      if square.state.nil?
        square.state = symbol
        break
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is: when I call `put_to_column` several times, it changes the `square` objects correctly, but only in the `@grid_strings` array. If I check the `@grid_columns` array, all `square` objects still have the `state` attribute assigned to nil.
I can't find the place where I made a mistake and hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find the place where I made a mistake and hope you can help.

Here it is

```
  square = column.pop
```

You're **removing** cells from a column. Look closely, you'll see the affected column become smaller. Also, the cell being removed is the one being modified, so that's why you never see the changes in the columns array.

Comment: But `column` variable is just a copy of my original column, isn't it?

Comment: @AnikeevGennadiy No, it isn't. It's a different reference for the same array object. If it was, indeed, a full copy, it's not clear why you would expect the changes to be reflected in another array's elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
@grid_columns = @grid_strings.transpose
```

`@grid_columns` and `@grid_strings` are **different objects**. Changing one will not change the other.

A possible alternative approach would be to define `grid_columns` as a **method**, which references the same object:

```
def grid_columns
  @grid_strings.transpose
end
```

There are other approaches you could also potentially use, but without knowing how you actually *use* the `grid_columns` it's hard to advise further.

Comment: That's not the problem. Arrays are different, yes, but they point to all the same squares.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ...but the squares aren't being changed here. The array itself is being mutated.

Comment: "The array itself is being mutated" - It is, but it's the error. The intent was to mutate squares. Or that's how I read it.

Comment: "but the squares aren't being changed here" - but they are :) That's what the whole question is _about_.